# Centering and allowing drag with d3 zoom

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, zooming

I'm working off of [this](http://bl.ocks.org/jhb/5955887) Block. My code has departed quite a bit from it, but I've just run into an issue (that I confirmed holds on the original Block).

When I add zoom/pan, the center of my force graph moves to the top left of the screen (which I can then pan down to center). And, I can't drag any nodes.

The zoom code I added is on the svg creation:

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
    svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
  }))
  .append("g");
```

Any thoughts on how to start the graph center and allow for dragging nodes?

Comment: well what is `d3.event.translate`?! It's probably null or 0,0 (which is top-left corner). It is also not evident in the code you have provided where you instantiate a `d3.drag()` object/event.

Comment: Hmmm. Good question! not sure what the value for `d3.event.translate` is. When I check it in the console it says "d3.event is null".  If you check the block link at the beginning, the ".call(force.drag)" is added to the "nodes" instantiation.

Comment: so you should probably set the correct translation for zoom. Assuming you want the cursor point to be the new "center" of the canvas, find the  differences for x and y between the center of the canvas (in regular js, that's derivable from `getBoundingClientRect()` and the element's `width` and `height` unsure of the d3 equivalent) and the mouse cursor on the zoom event (`d3.mouse(this)`?) and  and set those as the translate parameters.

Comment: The force layout is entirely asynchronous animation. In order for drag events to fire properly, the `tick` event must be hooked up to the force layout. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745398/why-do-we-need-force-ontick-in-d3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [D3 4.0 Graph with directed edges and labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39439608/d3-4-0-graph-with-directed-edges-and-labels)