# D3 force simulation in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I'm trying to have a d3 force simulation in Angular app. Basically what I have is `run` method that initialize and set simulation options and `ticked` method that updates simulation on each tick. I have a couple of problems related to this. (JavaScript version of the code works just fine)

My initial code is

```
private run() {
  this.simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  //some code
  this.simulation.on('tick', this.ticked())
}

private ticked() {
  //code
}
```

This does not work (simulation does not tick). But if I inline the `ticked` method like below, it works and simulation continues.

```
private run() {
  this.simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  //some code
  this.simulation.on('tick', () => {
   //code
  })
}
```

Is there a specific reason for this? I'm new to Angular and d3, it might be simple as how JavaScript behaves.

second question, previous code snippet (2nd one) works for few seconds and then simulation freeze. There are no error messages in the console. Can you guess why this is happening? 
I hope this is detailed enough. I can add more details if needed.

Comment: `this.ticked()` will execute the function right away and the expression will evaluate to the function's return value. You want to pass the function itself, instead: `this.simulation.on('tick', this.ticked)` (not the missing parentheses) which is basically equivalent to the inlined version which is alread working.

Comment: yep that makes sense. thanks for missing parentheses bit. It's so simple, now I feel stupid about asking this question. Do you have any idea why simulation is stopping after some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first attempt you made you was passing the return value from your method 'ticked' to the event function.

The event 'on' receives two parameters, the first is the event you are binding to, in this case 'tick' and a callback function that executes when the event returns a value. You was passing as second argument a value, and not a callback function. So it was executing your function before the event was triggered.

You can use your function 'ticked' with the callback like this:

```
this.simulation.on('tick', () => this.ticked());
```

Comment: That makes sense. Do you have any idea why simulation is stopping after some time.

Comment: I never used D3 before, but i found this link that maybe answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745398/why-do-we-need-force-ontick-in-d3

Comment: Thanks @Matheus, that question is not directly related but was useful understanding whats going on. I have some clues why its stopping after some time. I will try to investigate bit further. If I didn't get further answers, I'm going to mark this as correct answer tomorrow.